# How to do datatemplate for items in listbox?

Tags: wpf, xml, linq, xaml, datatemplate

I have an XML file (see below) and can display all the Product Names in a listbox.
I want each entry in the listbox to display Product Name followed by Price, not just Product Name.

How do I do the datatemplate in the XAML file? Thanks.

Simplified XML file:

```
<Product> 
<Name>Red Chair</Name> 
<Price>29.5</Price>  
</Product>
```

Simplified XAML file:

```
<DockPanel>      
<ListBox Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10" >      
</ListBox> 
</DockPanel>
```

In my C# file, I use LINQ to collect the products from the XML file and assign var products to listBox1.DataContext and it works fine. Now I just want to add in the Price. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this the same as any other `ItemTemplate`.

Make sure that you're binding to the `Product`, not the `Name`. You can then select the values from the XML using XPath, something like this.

```
<DockPanel>
  <ListBox Name="listBox1" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
           Margin="10" >       
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text={Binding XPath=./Name} />
          <TextBlock Text={Binding XPath=./Price} />
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your ItemsSource is of type `IEnumerable<Product>`, with

```cs
class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

you can set the item template like this:

```xml
<ListBox Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Price, StringFormat=f2}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Good but OP is binding to XML, not objects.

Comment: @Kirk: I was not able to deduce that from the question. "collect the products from the XML file" is not a technical term. With your answer, he can now choose. =)